# Getting Tier2 visa in UK

Tags: working-visas, uk-visa, job-hunting

I am an Indian citizen and I have already an exempt visa since I am working for an international organisation, I need to know what would be visa process if I want to switch job here in UK?

Do I need to go back to my home country and take an appointment there in UK embassy or there is some process to get the stamping done here in UK?

Do I need to get the visa before joining or there is some timeframe after joining?

Comment: Have you got a job offer from a company which will sponsor your tier 2 visa? They will be experienced in managing this process because only licenced companies can be sponsors. You can switch within the UK. More information https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general